# How to solve an invalid hook call error in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make an app using React Native and solve a problem that's been bugging me for a while. My latest attempt at solving it gave me an error: "Invalid hook call.". I'm sure my versions are matching, and I definitely only have one copy of React in the app, so apparently I'm breaking the Rules of Hooks.

I'm a relative beginner to making apps in React Native and I don't know where I'm breaking any rules with my use of hooks. As far as I can tell, I'm following the rules.

Here's the code I changed before the error threw:
RowCard.js

```
 //normal modal visibility handler


const RowCard = (props) => {
  
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  setModalVisible(props.modalVisible);
 

  return(
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.rowCard}
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        underlayColor={"white"}
        onPress={() => {setModalVisible(true) }}
        >

        <View style={styles.rowCard}>
          <Image source={{uri: props.image, width: 150, height: 150}} />
          <View style={styles.textBox}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>{props.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.ingredient}> Main ingredients: {props.ingredient1}, {props.ingredient2}, {props.ingredient3} </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  };

export default RowCard;
```

Here's the code for the other components I'm currently working on, for a broader context:
DrinkPopup.js:

```
const [idDrink, setIdDrink] = useState(0);

const DrinkPopup = (props) => {
  
  setIdDrink(props.idDrink);

  return(
    <Modal isVisible={props.modalVisible}
    onBackdropPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} //allows closing modal by tapping outside it or back button
    onBackButtonPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} 
    animationIn={"slideInUp"}>  
      <View style={styles.infocard}>
          <View style={styles.titleBox}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>{idDrink}</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>


  )


}
});
export default DrinkPopup;
```

And finally, AllList.js:

```
export default function AllList() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [drinkData,setDrinkData] = useState([]);
  const [searchValue, onChangeText] = useState(''); //needed for search
  const [reloading, setReloading] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false); //normal modal visibility handler
  const [idDrink, setIdDrink] = useState(0);

  useEffect (() =>  { 
    fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=' + searchValue)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setDrinkData(json.drinks))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      
  },[drinkData]);
  
  return (
    
    <View style = {styles.screen}>
      <View style = {styles.searchSection}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="Search Drinks..."  
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
          value={searchValue}/>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={drinkData}
        keyExtractor={({ idDrink }, index) => idDrink}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <RowCard id={item.idDrink} image={item.strDrinkThumb} title={item.strDrink} alcontent={item.strAlcoholic} 
            ingredient1={item.strIngredient1} ingredient2={item.strIngredient2} ingredient3={item.strIngredient3} setModalVisible={setModalVisible}
          />)}
        extraData={reloading}
        
      />
      <DrinkPopup modalVisible={modalVisible} setModalVisible={setModalVisible} drinkID={idDrink}/>
      
    </View>
      
  );

};
});
```

Where am I breaking the rules of hooks, and how do I follow them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  setModalVisible(props.modalVisible);
```

Where you are setting the modalVisible to a prop value.  This can likely be moved inside of a useEffect function to be called only on mount.  This is probably causing an error down the line when also using the same function here:

```
onBackdropPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}} //allows closing modal by tapping outside it or back button
onBackButtonPress={()=>{props.setModalVisible(false)}}
```

I'd probably start here:

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
 setModalVisible(props.modalVisible); 
}, [props.modalVisible]);
```

Hopefully this helps!

----update----

In response to your comment below regarding the too many renders, the issue is here:

```
    fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=' + searchValue)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setDrinkData(json.drinks))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      
  },[drinkData]);
```

The use effect hook is watching drinkData and when it changes, calls the function inside that hook.  In this case, the hook updates drinkData.

Comment: You should not have `props.modalVisible` in your `useEffect` without having it in your dependency array.
If you need to set this value only one time (on mount) then you should initialize your state with this value `const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(props.modalVisible)`

Comment: Good call @dbuchet will update, thank you!

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion and I'm now getting "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." located in DrinkPopup (at AllList.js:49), similar to the issue I had with @dbuchet's response

Comment: @dbuchet Thanks for the help, you guys! I think this did it, now I just need to figure out why my modal doesn't appear!

Answer (score 0):

Many code here, but I can directly point 2 errors:

```js
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
setModalVisible(props.modalVisible);
```

Do not use `setModalVisible` this way, but in `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => setModalVisible(props.modalVisible), [props.modalVisible]);
```

And

```js
const [idDrink, setIdDrink] = useState(0);

const DrinkPopup = (props) => {
  
  setIdDrink(props.idDrink);

  return ...
}
```

Why is your hook outside of your functional component?

```js
const DrinkPopup = (props) => {
    const [idDrink, setIdDrink] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => setIdDrink(props.idDrink), [props.idDrink]);
    ...
}
```

----update----

In response to your comment below regarding the too many renders, the issue is here:

```
    fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=' + searchValue)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setDrinkData(json.drinks))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      
  },[drinkData]);
```

The use effect hook is watching drinkData and when it changes, calls the function inside that hook.  In this case, the hook updates drinkData.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and they seemed to fix the problem, but I'm now getting "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Comment: That means your useEffect is certainly looping indefinitely. You should try to put some console.log to check which one is looping, and then check what are passed in their dependency array. Keep in mind that React does a `===` comparison. So if you have for example an empty array as dependency, and `[] === [] // false` your `useEffect` will loop

Comment: I think edit by @will should fix this :)
Your useEffect is triggered when `drinkData` changes, and your `useEffect` updates `drinkData`. So... infinite loop :)